# range.setStartBefore and range.setEndAfter don't work in Edge and IE11 in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

Though there are no errors, and both Edge and IE11 support [range.setStartBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStartBefore) and [range.setEndAfter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setEndAfter), nothing happens. I've checked each property and everything looks proper, yet highlighting/selecting the full range doesn't happen.

This works proper in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

To interact, select a couple characters or words in the middle of the lorem ipsum text. Chrome, Firefox, and Opera will select the rest of the lorem ipsum text like they're supposed to. Edge and IE11 do nothing.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEVzoe

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  range.setStartBefore(range.startContainer.parentNode);
  range.setEndAfter(range.endContainer.parentNode);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>Hi</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum aspernatur veniam ut accusamus, ratione nemo veritatis itaque, quia esse in recusandae qui pariatur tenetur non optio odio quis fugiat minima.</p>
  <p>Bye</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Edge & IE11 don't *visually* show it, the range is still being selected. You can see that by adding `range.deleteContents();` as the last line in the function callback.

**However**, that means that any editing behavior like rich text editing to change the style will ONLY use what's visually selected/highlighted, even if the actual range is different! :/